# How am I gaining muscle but not weight?

Tags: bodybuilding, muscle-gain, bodyweight

I am 19, 67kg and have been training for around 3-4 years so I am not a ‘newbie’. I am gaining muscle however whenever I weigh myself, I gain very little to no weight at all? I am confused as to where this weight is going as I’m low-ish body fat so I can’t be losing fat can I?

Comment: How can we possible answer a broad question like "I can't be losing fat can I?" based on handwavy details like "I'm low-ish body fat". Please include as much detail as possible. I mean, you haven't even included your gender. Also, training regimen, diet, and whatever else you can think of.

Comment: Also, it would help to know what *kind* of training, i.e. post a sample few days. It is entirely possibly that you are gaining strength without hypertrophy.

Comment: "I am gaining muscle" — what makes you say this? It's not clear.

Answer (score 1):

For this question to be properly answered more information is required.

What has changed in your routine, have you:

- Increased your daily training volume
- Increased your weekly volume
- Changed the style of training, high reps, low reps

1. Has your diet changed, more food or a change in your macro allotments?
2. Have you introduced any supplementation?
3. Have you added in any cardio?
4. How are you measuring your own strength increase, is it from looking in the mirror, muscle belly sizes or strength in the gym.

I will try to answer regardless.
My assumptions - nothing in your routine has changed and you have noticed your strength increasing but the scales staying static over this period.

The short answer is: Yes. You can gain muscle and lose fat at the same time. If your calorific intake is around maintenance with high enough protein intake in relation to your bodyweight, while providing your body with suitable stimulus, you will grow while losing fat. [[see: muscle gain, fat loss]](https://academic.oup.com/ajcn/article/103/3/738/4564609)

If you edit your post with more information, I may be able to go into specifics.
I hope this helps.